# How can I send a JSON PUT request to pipedrive from ACCESS using VBA?

Tags: json, vba

I use this converter: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

I can get the json data but i have got some text fields whith some text which schould update the data in pipedrive

```
Dim jsonUpload As String

Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")


jsonUpload = txt_pipedrive_id & ";"

jsonUpload = jsonUpload & txt_firma & ";"

jsonUpload = jsonUpload & txt_ansprechpartner & ";"

jsonUpload = jsonUpload & txt_adresse & ";"

jsonUpload = jsonUpload & txt_email & ";"

jsonUpload = jsonUpload & txt_telefon

Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(MyRequest.responseText)

MyRequest.Open "put", "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons/" & txt_pipedrive_id & "?api_token={api_token}"
MyRequest.Send.Json
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Why do you get `MyRequest.responseText` value prior to `MyRequest.Open` and `MyRequest.Send`? `MyRequest.Send.Json` is wrong syntax.